# Using BroadcastReceiver to get the playing position of a song

Tags: android

I know it should be possible to get the playing position of a song by using the IMediaPlaybackService from google music/htc player
But can I get the same info by BroadcastReceiver?

Answer (score 0):

No. The default IMediaPlaybackService implementation (see [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/src/com/android/music/MediaPlaybackService.java)) does not send any broadcasts with play position.

Comment: Is that means I will never ever get the play position by any method?

Comment: No. You can make hacks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786660/how-to-get-the-information-of-the-music-track-playing-on-a-android-device to get that position info. But it is complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing the audio file using the MediaPlayer class you could use this code to get the current position of the MediaPlayer:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
(Code to setup the MediaPlayer)
mp.getCurrentPosition();
```

You can't get info from the MediaPlaybackService, it's secured.